# Hide First Image in Product Gallery on Single Product Page WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I am trying to hide the product image on single product pages, while keeping the gallery as well as the featured image section (where users can view images in the gallery larger than thumbnail size.) To be clear, every product has a product image as well as a gallery. When viewing a single product page, it is as if there is a gallery for that product with the product image always the first to display in the gallery. I want to keep product image on all pages except single product page, where instead only the gallery for that product will appear on single product page. That is, can we remove the first image from the gallery (product image) on single product pages Is this possible?

EDIT
For anyone who is still looking for the solution, I have written this directly into my active child theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_attachment_ids', 'so_31818331_filter_gallery', 10, 2 );
function so_31818331_filter_gallery( $ids, $product ){
    if (is_product()) {
        set_post_thumbnail( $post, $ids[0] );
        unset($ids[0]);
    }
    else {
        set_post_thumbnail( $post, end($ids));
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

This will show the last image in the gallery as the thumbnail when not on a single product page, and it will show the first image in the gallery as the featured image on a single product page. Please keep in mind that this will also affect thumbnails for "Related Products" on a single product page as well. Will work on this, but in the meantime this should help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the code you are referring to.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimum Viable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then `edit` accordingly, so the question falls within SO guidelines.  So is designed so volunteers are able to efficiently help answer clear, specific questions that have definite, non-opinionated solutions.  Also, you can look at wordpress.stackexchange.com - a StackOverflow sister site dedicated to WordPress questions. It's possible they could have a post on this.

Comment: change https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/single-product/product-image.php#L40 to //$html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, true );
   $html = '';

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @jonathan could you please elaborate? Is this something I append in my active child theme's functions.php file? Also if you can rewrite the code you've supplied, as I believe you didn't mean to add the '//' to the beginning of the response?

Comment: At the top of the link that I have shared you can find the following; * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme / woocommerce / single-product / product-image.php. And the // are indeed the intention